# How to call a PHP variable from JavaScript in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

I'm trying to pass the longitude and latitude of a service to script that generates a google maps.
This is my code:

**Blade**

```
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>
<script>
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
scaleControl: true,
center: new google.maps.LatLng({{$servicio->Longitud}}}, {{$servicio->Latitud}}},
zoom:18
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: map.getCenter()
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div class="perfiles">
<legend>Detalle de servicio</legend>
<table class="table">
    <tr><td>Numero de Orden</td><td>{{$servicio->idServicio}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cliente</td><td>{{$servicio->Cliente}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Fecha Inicio</td><td>{{$servicio->Hora_Inicio}}</td></tr>
</table>
@if($servicio->Completado)
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:650px;height:300px;"></div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>{{HTML::image($servicio->RutaFoto1, '', array('width' => '300', 'height' => '300'))}}</td><td>{{HTML::image($servicio->RutaFoto2, '', array('width' => '300', 'height' => '300'))}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{HTML::image($servicio->RutaFoto3, '', array('width' => '300', 'height' => '300'))}}</td><td>{{HTML::image($servicio->RutaFoto4, '', array('width' => '300', 'height' => '300'))}}</td></tr>
    </table>
@endif
```

**Controller**

```
public function doDetail($id){
    $servicio = Servicio::find($id);
    return View::make('detalleservicio', array('servicio' => $servicio));

}
```

The problem is that the script does not recognize the code laravel or php. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you've got three }}} after Longitud and Latitud. I believe Longitud should be }} and Latitud should be }})

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng({{$servicio->Longitud}}}, {{$servicio->Latitud}}},
```

should be:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng({{$servicio->Longitud}}, {{$servicio->Latitud}}),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either use double curly brackets `{{` and `}}` or triple curly brackets `{{{` and `}}}`. You shouldn't mix one with the other.

Instead of

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng({{$servicio->Longitud}}}, {{$servicio->Latitud}}},
```

you should do

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng({{$servicio->Longitud}}, {{$servicio->Latitud}},
```

If you were to use `{{{` three curly brackets `}}}` instead of `{{` two `}}` then your output will be escaped, the angular brackets will be converted to HTML entities.

You can read more about echoing data using Blade templating engine here: http://laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures