# How to use Laravel Blade in a script file?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, laravel

I am trying to make a store locator app using this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) and Laravel 5. People in these questions [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243701/laravel-and-google-maps-foreach-latitude-longitude-show-marker-or-map) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619857/how-to-call-a-php-variable-from-javascript-in-laravel) seem to be using @foreach loops and other blade templating language to run through their lat/long coordinates. How are they doing that?

I basically do not know how to loop through coordinates using blade when my map code is in a js file? How is that possible? Am I doing something totally wrong?

I am showing my map with a js file (maps.js) that has the following code:

```
function initialize() {

var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map');

// Initialise the map
var map_options = {
    center: location,
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)

// Put all locations into array
var locations = [
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    [ {{ $article->lat }}, {{ $article->lng }} ]     
@endforeach
];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
    }); 
}

// marker.setMap(map); // Probably not necessary since you set the map above

}
```

But obviously that gets stuck on the @foreach line.

PS: If anyone has followed this tutorial with Laravel 5 I would be grateful for any info on this part: Outputting XML with PHP.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**There is no way to use Blade templating within an external Javascript file.**

Laravel can only pass data to a view/template; Javascript files are loaded externally and therefore App data is not passed to them.

In order to get around this, you need to create `<script>` tags within your Blade template file:

```
{{-- Code in your template file, e.g., view.blade.php --}}

<script type="text/javascript">

// Put all locations into array
var locations = [
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    [ "{{ $article->lat }}", "{{ $article->lng }}" ], 
@endforeach
];

// NOTE: I've added a comma which will be needed to delimit each array within the array.
//       Quotes will also be needed since lat and long are not integers.

</script>
```

Make sure that this snippet comes ***before*** the code for including your `maps.js` file.  If you've inlcuded the `maps.js` file within your `<head>` tags, you're going to need to move that inclusion snippet down to the bottom of the page.

This is a rather rudimentary solution, however.  A better way would be to use AJAX to retrieve the data from within your `maps.js` file upon initialization.

This would, of course, require you to create a new Controller method and corresponding route that can handle the request and return the required data.

Comment: This worked perfect for me! But, is there any way to do it with multiple variables? For example, if I wanted to put content into each of the markers. How could I do that?

Comment: what do you mean?

in your controller you could just pass more variables.. like `view('myView', ['variable1' => $variable1, 'variable2' => $variable2, etc...])`;

Comment: Yeah, I would like to put separate arrays within the variable locations. For instance, for each location, I would also like to inject the title of the location and some other information. After seeing this post, I posted another question in this regard. Maybe this will help clarify my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924237/laravel-5-4-blade-javascript-google-maps-insert-foreach-with-multiple-variabl

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `JavaScript` object from the `Eloquent` object, for example take a look at the following code:

```
// index.blade.php
<script>var userObj = {{ $authUser or 'undefined' }}</script>
```

This is a `blade` view and I'm just loading the `view` and passing the `collection` to the view using something like this (Using a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers)):

```
View::composer('layouts.master', function($view) {
    $user = null;
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
    }
    $view->with('authUser', $user);
});
```

So, in my `view` I've `$authUser` so I can convert it to `JS` object easily like:

```
<script>var userObj = {{ $authUser or 'undefined' }}</script>
```

So now, I can use it as a `JS` object which is in `userObj` variable (JavaScript). Check [this article of mine](http://heera.it/laravel-pass-user-object-javascript-object#.VjgP7tIrLIU) that I've written nearly a year ago for `Laravel-4`.

Answer (score 3):

In the samples you provided, they are using blade because they are in a blade file, and all JavaScript is between  tags. It is not a .js filetype, so you can use blade language features this way.