# why I can't make a request from jquery to laravel route?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, post, routes

I'm trying to make a post request via jquery but It seems to be something wrong.

**Route:**

```
Route::post('fblogin','UserController@fblogin')->name('fblogin');
```

**Jquery:**

```
$.post( "{{route('fblogin')}}", { 'response': response, '_token':'{{ csrf_token() }}' }, function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function fblogin(Reqeust $request)
    {           
            var_dump($request->response);
    }
```

Comment: Is your jQuery in a js file, or in a blade.php file? Blade structures and PHP will not work if it's in a js file.

Comment: it is in a .js file

Comment: You'll have to hard-code the route instead of using the blade syntax/PHP function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Laravel Blade in a script file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489931/how-to-use-laravel-blade-in-a-script-file)

Comment: You can use this [package](https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy)

Comment: You haven't described the error/failure in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I you are in a js file you cannot use blade's mustache syntax {{ }}.

But if you want you can set the 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' header globaly to jQuery

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  headers : {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : token.content
  }
});

$.post(window.location.origin + '/fblogin', { 'response': response, '_token': token.content }, function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

And if you want to generate your route dynamically there are several way to do that, among which [this package](https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy)

Answer (score 0):

oh my, it is a typewriting issue:

check the controller first line, it is "Reqeust $request" but it should be "Request $request"

I'm not sure why doesn't it returned an error or anything.

Comment: Because it doesn't get that far. See the comments, the URL is not being generated in the javascript.

Comment: I didn't understand the question the first time. I thought that you are asking about the jquery.min.js file. But the jquery request code is in a blade php file. Sorry for the misunderstanding