# How to set javascript variable to laravel blade file?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am not able to set my javascript variable for my blade file:

```
$filterCoupons = data;
```

I want to use this variable in a loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489931/how-to-use-laravel-blade-in-a-script-file Try this

Comment: @anwerj i want to use variable data inside blade file, link is for the blade file variable into js

Comment: It is not possible to do this in that way. Where are coming from your `data`? Please, add the relevant code in your post.

Comment: From javascript to PHP, use ajax request(or whatever request format you like). From PHP to javascript, you can have interpolation `{{}}` to assign the value.

Comment: js


js
Javascript:- var data = coupons.filter(e => e.service_type_id == id || e.coupon_type == 1 || e.coupon_type == 4);

laravel blade file
@foreach($filterCoupons as $key => $value)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<script>
    let data = {{json_encode($filterCoupons)}}
</script>
```

Or you can put all filters into array

```
var data = [ {{ implode(",", $filterCoupons )}} ];
```

Comment: `You cannot assign a php variable to a javascript variable` maybe you meant the other way round. Also, the values filled in that `foreach` won't be comma separated. You could better use `{{ implode(",",$filterCoupons ) }}` instead of looping.

Comment: @vivek_23 You are true, I just want him to know the idea not only copy and paste the code, But any way I'll Edit it.